# Why is my program counting too many collisions?

Tags: java, sprite, collision

I'm trying to record every time that my sprites collide with each other. Unfortunately my current solution seems to be adding more collisions to the count than necessary and I don't understand why.

I've tried many different forms of collision tracking but all ultimately suffer from the same flaw: they count collisions that have not happened. My current solution will count 10 collisions if none occur, which is significantly more accurate than previous methods but not accurate enough for my needs.

Here is the rectangle I am using to check for collisions:

```java
    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        if (rotate){
            return new Rectangle((int) x, (int) y, 60, 40);
        }else{
            return new Rectangle((int) x, (int) y, 40, 60);
        }

    }
```

Here is my collisionCheck() method using .intersects:

```java
Rectangle r2 = null;
    public void checkCollisions(){
        for (Iterator<SimpleSprite> it = Carpaint.Cars.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            Carpaint c = (Carpaint) it.next();
            if (c.dx > 0 || c.dy > 0){
                Rectangle r1 = c.getBounds();
                System.out.println(r1);
                if (r2 != null){
                    if (r1.intersects(r2) && r2.intersects(r2)){
                        Carpaint.collisions ++;
                        System.out.println("Car r1: " + r1 + "collided with Car r2" + r2);
                    }
                }
                r2 = r1;
                System.out.println(r2);
                }
        }
    }
```

And this gets called every 50 milliseconds by

```java
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
checkCollisions();
```

When I ran the program for 3 seconds I could see that none should occur however every time I tested it I would get 10 or more results. How can I fix this?

EDIT:
Changed the code to fix an error; it is now

```java
if (r1.intersects(r2) && r2.intersects(r1)){
```

However the result is still the same

Comment: wouldn't r2.intersects(r2) be always true?

Comment: Good point but even after I fixed that it still gave the same result

Comment: One other thing to note is that these ten collisions seem to be recorded at the start of the loop before things go back to normal (sorta)

Comment: Try to print the collisions before the loop and inside the if(r1.intersects(r2)) block.

Comment: Have you tried to actually debug the problem? Set a breakpoint at `Carpaint.collisions++` and manually check the situation in which your program counts a collision. You said you expected the number of collisions to be zero, so debugging should be simple. You only have to inspect the first case where a collision is counted. If you get stuck, give us a minimal complete example for that single case you observed.

Comment: Sorry for the answer.. this is more of a comment. You said that this code runs every 50ms. So, you need to clear the value of Carpaint.collisions at the start of this function or did I understand this incorrectly?

Comment: collisions is a static variable in the Carpaint object so I don't think I need to reset it

Comment: @Socowi thanks for the tip about debugging - figured out that the method was comparing the cars to their previous position and counting that as a collision. Still unsure on how to proceed.